# Animate clipping in UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

The following XAML-code creates a box where half on the content is clipped:

```xml
<Grid Width="90"
        Height="34"
        Background="Red"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="2">
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,45,34" />
    </Grid.Clip>
    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="4">Hello world</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Is it possible to create a storyboard with an animation which gradually changes the clipping from left to right? The documentation indicates something like this, "[The animation targets a sub-property value of these UIElement properties: Transform3D, RenderTransform, Projection, Clip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/storyboarded-animations#other-properties-of-an-animation)", but I haven’t found a sample of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To animate clipping in UWP, we can use [ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br210320) with `Grid.Clip` like following:

```xml
<Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Grid.Clip">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,55,34" />
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.50">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,65,34" />
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.75">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,75,34" />
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,90,34" />
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
...
<Grid x:Name="grid"
      Width="90"
      Height="34"
      Background="Red"
      BorderBrush="Black"
      BorderThickness="2"
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,45,34" />
    </Grid.Clip>

    <TextBlock Margin="4" Foreground="White">Hello world</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

However this is a key-frame animation, if you need a linear interpolation animation, you can try like following:

```xml
<Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1"
                     Storyboard.TargetName="grid"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Clip).(Geometry.Transform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                     To="0" />
</Storyboard>
...
<Grid x:Name="grid"
      Width="90"
      Height="34"
      Background="Red"
      BorderBrush="Black"
      BorderThickness="2"
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,90,34">
            <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-45" />
            </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
        </RectangleGeometry>
    </Grid.Clip>

    <TextBlock Margin="4" Foreground="White">Hello world</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you, that really explains everything. If it was possible I would give you an extra point for the syntax in Storyboard.TargetProperty :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use DispatcherTimer and change the Rect property in its Tick event handler. Something like this:

```
<RectangleGeometry x:Name="rec" Rect="0,0,45,34" />

DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
timer.Start();

private void timer_Tick(...)
{
    rec.Rect = new Rectangle(left, top, width, height);
}
```